# Deploy Photon Controller 1.2 on ESXi 6.0 success but cannot access load balancer port 4343

Tags: kubernetes, vmware, esxi, photon-controller

I follow the SOP published by VMWare https://vmware.github.io/photon-controller/assets/files/Photon_Controller_Getting_Started_Guide_20151116.pdf

After I deploy photon-controller 1.2 on ESXi 6.0 success, and I wants to access load balancer (haproxy) via GUI https://:4343. I found that I cannot reach it.

[image]

After that I login into the load balancer VM and dump the tcp port, only port 22 enabled but no port 4343 or other ports. How do I troubleshoot and solve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found that solution that the load balancer (haproxy) needs to reboot once, and then TCP port 443 and 4343 will enable.